# Bootstrap form validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to validate a form using jquery because i need to call the controller method only after the insertion of a second form. Previously i had an input of type submit and when i clicked it the result was the following alert: 
[image]

Now i changed the input to button type that displays a modal and i want to show the same alert when i click the button, i tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$('#formContratto').validate({
            rules: {
                NumeroAutobus: {
                    required: true
                },
                Descrizione: {
                    required: true
                },
                DocContratto: {
                    required: true
                },
                NumeroAutorizzazione: {
                    required: true
                },
                DataScadenza: {
                    required: true
                },
                idAbbonamento: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function (element) {
                element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('Done');
            }   
        });
```

That's the input button:

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="button" value="@Risorse.Language.InserisciAutorizzazione" class="btnRegister btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm" onclick="submitform();" /></div>
```

And that's the script of the page:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

            $('#formContratto').validate({
                rules: {
                    NumeroAutobus: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    Descrizione: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    DocContratto: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    NumeroAutorizzazione: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    DataScadenza: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    idAbbonamento: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                },
                success: function (element) {
                    element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('Done');
                }   
            });
        });

        $('#modalLoginForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var button = e.relatedTarget;
            if ($("#NumeroAutobus").val().length == 0
                || $("#Descrizione").val().length == 0
                || $("#DocContratto").val().length == 0
                || $("#NumeroAutorizzazione").val().length == 0
                || $("#DataScadenza").val().length == 0
                || $("#idAbbonamento").val().length == 0) {
                e.stopPropegation();
            }
        });

        function submitform() {
            debugger;
            var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
            if (f.checkValidity()) {
                f.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So, is it working but message look and feel is different? Or it is completely not working?

Comment: It's not working at all

Comment: Is your form created by default on the page load or it is getting dynamically added after some events?

Comment: i edit the post with the script part of the page and the button code

Comment: Where is your form getting created?

Comment: In the page i have the form as follows:
<form id="formContratto">
some things
</form>

Comment: In Modal right?

Comment: Nope, this is a normal form, i do not implement yet the form in the modal. At the moment, i'm working on the validation of this first form.

Comment: For now, I have put the form in the modal and applied the validations. Kindly check my answer and let me know in case of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.

On the method where i display the modal i added the else statement as follows:

```
 $('#modalLoginForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var button = e.relatedTarget;
    if ($("#NumeroAutobus").val().length == 0
        || $("#Descrizione").val().length == 0
        || $("#DocContratto").val().length == 0
        || $("#NumeroAutorizzazione").val().length == 0
        || $("#DataScadenza").val().length == 0
        || $("#idAbbonamento").val().length == 0) {
        e.stopPropegation();
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

With preventDefault i avoided the call to the server and i open the modal correctly. Hope it'll helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this:

1. Your button needs to be set to type="submit"
2. Your submit button should be present inside your form tag

Find the working fiddle below. If you don't want to put the form in the modal, you can just take your form out.

I have edited my fiddle. You can use `submitHandler` method to prevent form's default action by using `e.preventDefault();` and handle your next actions.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#formContratto").validate({
    rules: {
      NumeroAutobus: {
        required: true
      },
      Descrizione: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      NumeroAutobus: {
        required: "Please enter some data"
      },
      Descrizione: {
        required: "Please provide some data"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form,e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Form submitted');
            return false;
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="formContratto">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">First Field:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NumeroAutobus" name="NumeroAutobus" placeholder="Enter first field" require/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Second Field:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descrizione" name="Descrizione" placeholder="Enter second field" require>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this.
It validates correctly the form but when i click the save button, it opens the modal that i require but also launch the controller method. How can i solve it?

Comment: You mean how to perform server call?

Comment: Nope, i have a form which is **not** in the modal. When i click the save button of this first form i need to validate the fields and then, to open the second form which is in the modal. I need to avoid that this first click perform the server call.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can utilize `submitHandler` to prevent form from submitting the server call and take required actions.

Comment: So, you can use my for as default form on your page and then use `submitHandler` to open moadl for second form

Comment: Thank you, i solved this anyway. You can look how i did it with my answer.